# After Successful Installation Magento Getting Blank Gray page for Admin

Tags: php, magento2

Getting Blank Page Like this after Installing Magento Successfully Iam not able to track where it was gone wrong anyone could you please help me with this

[image]

This is the Front end screen iam able to see even i installed with sample data

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

Fix taken from [Magento Community Forums](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/After-Successful-Installation-Magento-Getting-Blank-Gray-page/td-p/114080), posted here for anyone who finds this query first (SO has better SEO than Magento forums)

**excerpt below**

in the directory path
`...\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php`
In the function `isPathInDirectories` add a line

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $realPath);
```

refer below for where to insert

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }
    $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
    $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $realPath); // extra code added
    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score -1):

What is the deployed mode of your current install? (Default, Developer or Production?)

If it is the default mode, you can track what is your problem on var/log/system/log
More detail about Magento2 modes, you can reference here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

Regards,
Bach

Comment: Please do not post queries as answers. You can ask your questions in comments below the question.